# Блок меняющий свою ширину в зависимости от наличия левого блока меню

Tags: css, html

Есть общая обёртка, шириной 1024px, внутри есть блок левого меню, и горизонтальный блок ссылок. Схематично всё можно представить так:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 1024px">
<div id="left-menu" style="float: left; width: 200px;">
  <ul>
    <li>Меню 1
    <li>Меню 2
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="top-panel" style="border: 1px solid black;">
 <a>Ссылка 1</a><a>Ссылка 2</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Проблема в следующем. На некоторых страницах блока с левым меню нет. Если задать блоку top-panel:

```
style="width: 100%;"
```

Тогда он растягивается на весь блок в 1024px когда меню нет, а в случае появлению меню, текст в блоке смещается как нужно, но граница блока оказывается под блоком left-menu, что неприемлемо.

Если выставить display: inline для top-panel; то рамка не залазит под left-menu, но размер блока top-panel уменьшается до размера содержимого, что опять же неприемлемо.

В общем вопрос, как правильно сверстать блоки так, чтобы ширина блока top-panel всегда составляла всю доступную ширину родительского блока, уменьшаясь при появлении блока с меню?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант с использованием `display: flex`

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {  
  display: flex;
  border: 4px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.left-menu { 
  width: 200px;  
}
.top-panel {
  border: 1px solid black;  
  flex: 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Меню 1
        <li>Меню 2
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-panel">
    <a>Ссылка 1</a>
    <a>Ссылка 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">  
  <div class="top-panel">
    Без левого сайдбара
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант с использованием `display: table`

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {  
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid black;  
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.left-menu,
.top-panel{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left-menu { 
  width: 200px;  
}
.top-panel {
  border: 1px solid black;    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Меню 1
        <li>Меню 2
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-panel">
    <a>Ссылка 1</a>
    <a>Ссылка 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">  
  <div class="top-panel">
    Без левого сайдбара
  </div>
</div>
```